# How to get the IDs of the all documents from the firebase using flutter web

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to have a list contains the IDs of the documents in a collection [image]for using the id as string in comparison with something else but I couldn't find the way to do that

I wrote the following

```
final firebaseid = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Guests').get().then((value) {
  var id = value;
  print(id);
});
```

but I couldn't get the documents ids

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a list of all ids in a collection like this:

```
  void getAllGuestsIds() async {
    final docIds = await FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Guests').get().then(
          (value) => value.docs.map((e) => e.id).toList(),
        );
    //return or do something else with docIds
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CollectionReference _collectionRef =
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');

Future<void> getData() async {
    QuerySnapshot querySnapshot = await _collectionRef.get();

    final allData = querySnapshot.docs.map((doc) => doc.data()).toList();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

While [Murat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75987012/209103) will get you the data of all documents, you seem to be asking for the document IDs. In that case, you'll want:

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('Guests').get().then((querySnapshot) {
  for (var doc in querySnapshot.docs) {
    var id = doc.id;
    print(id);
  }
});
```

The big difference here is that the code handles the fact that the result of [calling `get` on a `CollectionReference`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/Query/get.html) is a [`QuerySnapshot`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/QuerySnapshot-class.html), and you'll need to loop over its `docs` to get each individual document. This is also shown in the Firebase documentation on [getting all documents in a collection](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#dart_6).